# Scraping next page with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get to the Next page on a tripadviser scrape using BeautifulSoup.  The Next page href looks like this:

```
<a href="/Hotels-g186338-oa60-London_England-Hotels.html#ACCOM_OVERVIEW" data-page-number="3" data-offset="60" class="nav next ui_button primary taLnk" onclick="ta.hac.filters.paging(this, event); ta.trackEventOnPage('STANDARD_PAGINATION', 'next', '3', 0);">Next</a>
```

At the moment I'm trying:

```
url_base='https://tripadviser.co.uk/'
next_page_link = url_base + elm['href']

response = requests.get(url_base+next_page_link)
html = response.content
```

Comment: Next page on the pagination??

Comment: Yes, next page on the pagination

Comment: That way it's not going to work...you are getting the same page, right?

Comment: No, I'm getting an error but I think I've just sorted it because I think it is that I'm adding url_base twice

Comment: Are you sure....I think that that kind of pagination is based on javascript....if that results to be the case then you are going to need something more functional like Selenium.

Comment: yes, it is definitely working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected this code:
`response = requests.get(next_page_link)`